# Image page transition

Tags: javascript, css, user-interface, transition, fadein

Does anyone have any idea how to have an image transition to another page without re-loading.  There is a good example of this on http://nahelmoussi.com/ .

When you click on a case study image, the image gets bigger and stays on the page.

I know you could use CSS Transitions for the animation but what I'm confused about is how you load a whole new page (different page for SEO) and make it so the image never looks like it's reloading?

Comment: It's called [SPA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-page_application).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## [`history.pushState()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/History_API#The_pushState()_method)

> The DOM window object provides access to the **browser's history** through the history object. It exposes useful methods and properties that let you move back and forth through the user's history, as well as -- starting with HTML5 -- **manipulate the contents of the history** stack.
>
> `pushState()` takes three parameters: a state object, a title (which is currently ignored), and (optionally) a URL.

### And [AJAX](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/AJAX/Getting_Started)

> AJAX stands for Asynchronous JavaScript And XML. In a nutshell, it is the use of the XMLHttpRequest object to communicate with servers. It can send and receive information in various formats, including JSON, XML, HTML, and text files. AJAX’s most appealing characteristic is its "asynchronous" nature, which means it can communicate with the server, exchange data, and **update the page without having to refresh the page**.

After animating the image, we can update the browser's history by appending a new location, and use AJAX to fetch the new content.

Manipulating the `history` allows that the user can navigate back and forth in the same way they would if they had navigated to a new location the *traditional* way.

We can use AJAX to fetch new data, and optionally change parts or all of the page content to show this new data.

The effect of the combined methods is that after clicking the image:

- The image expands.
- The rest of the content is either hidden or overwritten.
- New data is fetched.
- The new data is displayed.
- The `history` is updated.
- It appears to the user that they have navigated to a new location (and their browser history will show that they did), but that the image they originally clicked remained on their screen at all times.

### An unrefined and basic demo:

Although not *fully* functional, this will demonstrate the fundamentals of the process if served by a `localhost`. The scope of the question is too wide for a narrow demo, and a wide enough demo to show the full functionality would require building an entire demonstration website.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Page 1</title>
    <script async>
      ( function( W, D ) {
        var handlePopstate = function( evt ) {
            // handle history navigation through evt.state
            console.log( evt.state );
          },
          getNewContentAndUpdateHistory = function( d, p ) {
            // create and call ajax for new content using destination URL
            console.log( d );
            // update the browser's history and the history.state
            history.pushState( { ps: p }, "", d );
            // handle history navigation through history.state
            console.log( history.state );
          },
          init = function() {
            D.addEventListener( "click", function( evt ) {
              var trg = evt.target;
              if ( trg.tagName.toLowerCase() === "img" && !trg.classList.contains( "bg" ) ) {
                var dest = trg.getAttribute( "data-href" ),
                  page = /(\d+)/.exec( dest )[ 1 ];
                trg.classList.add( "bg", "_" + page );
                // load, parse and display new content and update the browser's history
                getNewContentAndUpdateHistory( dest, page );
              }
            }, false );
          };
        if ( /^(?:complet|interactiv)e$/.test( D.readyState ) ) {
          init();
        } else {
          W.addEventListener( "DOMContentLoaded", init, false );
        }
        W.addEventListener( "popstate", handlePopstate, false );
      } ( window, document ) );
    </script>
    <style>
      html {
        font-size: 10px;
      }
      body {
        font-family: sans-serif;
        font-size: 1.6rem;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
      img {
        position: relative;
        display: block;
        width: 400px;
        height: 200px;
        cursor: pointer;
        transition: width 1s, height 1s;
      }
      .bg {
        position: absolute;
        width: 100vw;
        height: 100vh;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        cursor: default;
      }
      ._2 {
        z-index: 2;
      }
      ._3 {
        z-index: 3;
      }
      ._4 {
        z-index: 4;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Foo</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.<img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200" data-href="page/2/"></p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.<img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200" data-href="page/3/"></p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.<img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200" data-href="page/4/"></p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for the in depth reply.  I understand now what it is, I'm going to look around for more examples and demos.  I appreciate it!

Comment: @echoes-in-eternity - I'm pleased to help you. If you're satisfied that I have answered your question, it would help me and other people searching for similar information if you accepted my answer by clicking the tick icon at the top left of the answer - under the voting arrows.

Comment: Thank you @FredGandt.  So, after more research and tinkering around I've found a few blogs that give more in depth examples of how to use pushstate and ajax.  I'm able to create an SPA with these methods, however I'm still having trouble getting an image to animate from page to page similar to [link](http://nahelmoussi.com/).  I'm using css transition animations but the image still reloads as a result of the new content coming in.

Comment: @echoes-in-eternity - If you inspect the HTML of the site you link, you'll see that all the content of all the "pages" is present all the time (not even fetched by AJAX). The `pushstate` stuff is **only** keeping track of the changes of which section is being actively viewed. Everything else that happens is animation; you're only looking at one long "page", with sections being designated separate "pages". To emulate it, if you ignore the `pushstate` stuff while concentrating on the web-design, you can simply add the `pushstate` stuff to update the browsing history afterwards.